# How can I change my hearthfire house wings In Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I tried sqv byohhousefalkreath but that only showed things like hold and hold city not the rooms in my house. Is there any other commands I can try to change my house wings??